# Will long-lasting readOnly transaction slow down other request?

Tags: postgresql

For example, I want to iterate over `5000k` rows via without holder `cursor` inside a readOnly transaction, it will definitely run for a long period.

Will such kind transaction slow down other requests on the same table ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it won't, unless concurrent transaction require an `ACCESS EXCLUSIVE` lock on the table (they are running something like `DROP TABLE`, `ALTER TABLE` or `CREATE INDEX`). Such transactons would hang until the read-only transaction is done.

The problem with long transactions is that they keep autovacuum from doing its work, and if there is a lot of concurrent data modifying activity, you could end up with bloated tables and indexes.

Comment: One more question, will all rows of that query have to keep all its version util transaction end, or just some rows that are currently being read ?

Comment: All row versions that are still valid for some open transaction will be kept, unless you set the parameter [`old_snapshot_threshold`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-resource.html#GUC-OLD-SNAPSHOT-THRESHOLD) (available since 9.6) to a value different from the default -1. In that case, old row versions that would still be needed could also be removed, which could lead to an error for the long running transaction.

Comment: Will forward only cursor help autovacuum ?

Comment: Autovacuum will not reclaim rows that are still visible by any active transaction. So what you could do is [`DECLARE c CURSOR WITH HOLD ...`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-declare.html) in SQL and then commit the transaction. This cannot be done with cursors declared in PL/pgSQL.

Comment: But withhold cursor will dump rows to temp file, won't it be expensive if the result set is very large ?

Comment: Yes, it will cost disk space on the server.